# Render land based on relation of ways with geosever and data from OSM

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap

I have styles for ways and polygons in a geoserver setup. However the land is not being properly rendered.
I have notice that the feature for 'Arabia' (https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/5631846#map=12/28.6282/48.4909) is a relation of ways.
What I have done is download OSM data and import it into `postgis` with `osm2pgsql`, so this relation ends up in the lines table and my current styles for lines don't fit.
So, which SDL will render the relation of lines as an area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [many issues](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Coastline) with trying to use the OSM `natural=coastline` lines as a polygon. The usual solution is to download one of the pre prepared [coastline shapefiles](http://data.openstreetmapdata.com/land-polygons-split-3857.zip) discussed on the wiki page.